# Is there a list of python exit codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit, exit-code

I'm searching for a list of ALL python exit codes, for learning reasons, and just from interest and curiosity, but it seems I can't find any list that contains all the exit codes...
Thanks
I know that Zero means a successful exit. I don't have a question about a specific one... just for general knowledge I want to know some (and a list of all) the exit codes

**answer: there is no such list.**

Comment: Maybe you can find it here ? https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#process-management

Comment: Not a duplicate... I can't find a list that states which exit code means what

Comment: @AmitKeren: If you read the answers carefully there, you'd have learned that *there is no such list*.